# Unable to set the ListFillRangeProperty of the DropDown class

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel workbook that has been working but this morning have en-counted an error.

The error message I get is,

> Run-time error 1004
>   Unable to set the ListFillRangeProperty of the DropDown class

Below is my code - the error happens at `ws.DropDowns("DropDownStart")`.

DropDownStart and DropDownEnd are the correct names for the drop downs on my sheet so not sure what is causing this error. When I debug print the name I get

`mysheetName!$A$2:$A$338`

which is correct and all the cells contain dates in them. So bit stuck!

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wsTime As Worksheet
Set wsTime = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(WSTSJPM)
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(WSCHARTS)

' get last date
Dim lRow As Long
lRow = wsTime.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
ws.Select
ws.DropDowns("DropDownStart").ListFillRange = wsTime.Name & "!" & wsTime.Range("A2:A" & lRow).Address
ws.DropDowns("DropDownEnd").ListFillRange = wsTime.Name & "!" & wsTime.Range("A2:A" & lRow).Address
```

**Update for comments**

I can change the dropdown manually the code can change it normally too. The workbook is not being shared.

The sheet name contain no spaces in it.

I believe I should be using an "=" in the fill range unless you know another way?

The DropDown is a form control of type list box and is on my worksheet

Comment: Is it possible to change the properties of dropdown manually? Under some conditions - for example when the workbook is in shared mode - you can't change it.

Comment: Does the sheet name contain spaces?

Comment: Should you be using an "=" in the fill range:
`=mysheetName!$A$2:$A$338`

Comment: I get an error on the same line as you, but this one : `Run-time error 1004` `Method 'DropDowns' of object'_Worksheet' failed`. What do you mean by "DropDowns"?

Answer (score 0):

Another problem looks like you have no quotes around the sheet names.
This code seems to work for me

```
Sub populatecombobox()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wsTime As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long

    Set wsTime = Sheets("WSTSJPM")
    Set ws = Sheets("WSCHARTS")

    With wsTime
        lRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    ws.DropDowns("DropDownStart").ListFillRange = "WSTSJPM!$A$2:$A$" & lRow
    ws.DropDowns("DropDownEnd").ListFillRange = "WSTSJPM!$A$2:$A$" & lRow

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi sorry, I should have mentioned the sheet names are actually global variables so that's not an issue & spelt correctly so that's not an issue.